# Getting error in the jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am getting the below error - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute

I have tried to search the net but non of the solution is solving this issue.

Please find my controller class

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showLoginPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("login", new LoginBean());
        return "login";
    }
}
```

login.jsp file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<body>
    <h2>Information</h2>
    <form:form method="POST">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="emailId">Name</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="emailId" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="password">Age</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

LoginBean.java class

```
public class LoginBean {
    public LoginBean() {
    }
    private String emailId;
    private String password;

    public LoginBean(String emailId, String password) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Any Help will be highly appreciated.Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should add following commandName attribute in your form in JSP:

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="login">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="emailId">Name</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="emailId" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="password">Age</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
```

Because otherwise spring form does not understand  which object your refer to.